# Applescript Replace all <br> tags with empty lines?

Tags: applescript

This code gets two bits of two and copies them to the clipboard.

One bit of text is html. Before stripping out all the html I want to replace the 
 tags with empty lines.

I can't get the 
 replaced correctly, but the rest of the code works.

Any idea what I am doing wrong. I also tried using return instead of linefeed.

```
tell application "GarageSale 7"
    repeat with theListing in (get selected ebay listings)
        set des to get the description of theListing
        set comment to get private comment of theListing
    end repeat
end tell

set theText to des


to searchReplace(thisText, "<br>", linefeed)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to searchTerm
    set thisText to thisText's text items
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to replacement
    set thisText to "" & thisText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
    return thisText
end searchReplace


on removeMarkupFromText(theText)
    set tagDetected to false
    set theCleanText to ""
    repeat with a from 1 to length of theText
        set theCurrentCharacter to character a of theText
        if theCurrentCharacter is "<" then
            set tagDetected to true
        else if theCurrentCharacter is ">" then
            set tagDetected to false
        else if tagDetected is false then
            set theCleanText to theCleanText & theCurrentCharacter as string
        end if
    end repeat
    return theCleanText
end removeMarkupFromText

get the clipboard
set the clipboard to removeMarkupFromText(theText) & comment
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a handler called `searchReplace()`, but you never actually use it. That's why your script isn't replacing the `<br>` tags.

Firstly, you want to define the handler properly. It should take arguments that are represented by variables; currently, your last two arguments are specific values:

```
to searchReplace(thisText, "<br>", linefeed)
```

Here's a suggested edit:

```
to searchReplace(thisText, searchTerm, replacement)
    set my text item delimiters to searchTerm
    set thisText to thisText's text items
    set my text item delimiters to replacement
    set thisText to thisText as text
    set my text item delimiters to {""}
    return thisText
end searchReplace
```

Then you can call it from your script like so:

```
tell application "GarageSale 7"
    repeat with theListing in (get selected ebay listings)
        set des to get the description of theListing
        set comment to get private comment of theListing
    end repeat
end tell

set theText to searchReplace(des, "<br>", linefeed) 
set the clipboard to removeMarkupFromText(theText) & comment
```